How to Resolve "Google hasn’t verified this app" Issue for Firebase Social Login with Google?
I am implementing Google login using Firebase for my web application. I've set up the OAuth consent screen in the Google Developer Console and added the following scopes:

/auth/userinfo.email
/auth/userinfo.profile
openid

In developer console, I can see that app is also verified. Please see screenshot

Despite this, when users try to log in, they see the following error message:

I have completed the initial setup as follows:

Created a project in the Google Developer Console.
Configured the OAuth consent screen with the necessary information.
Added the three scopes mentioned above.
Verified my domain in the Google Developer Console.

How can I ensure that my users don’t see the "Google hasn’t verified this app" warning message?

Based on your screenshots the app is verified to request only those 3 scopes. If you're seeing an "unverified app" screen, you are probably actually requesting more scopes than those you are verified for.
Look for the scopes being requested in your code (not just those registered in the cloud console).
See https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en#unverified-app-screen.
You can also use this section if you're not sure how to find the scopes being requested in your application: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/granular-permissions#how-to-determine-if-your-application-is-using-multiple-scopes
